# Backbone extend a model before rendering it to a template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to pass additional variables to my template, i.e. some that are not contained within a model. These are basically display parameters like how the screen will appear to the user next. It doesn't have to be saved in the database.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
render: function () {
         this.extra_list = _.shuffle(this.extra_list);
         jQuery.extend(this.model, this.extra_list);
         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));..
         return this;
      }
```

When I make a reference to extra_list in the template I get an error that the variable is not defined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

`model.toJSON()` returns a model's *attributes* not properties. Since your extend function is adding those properties directly to the model, they are undefined when you pass the output of `toJSON` to your template.

Either add `extra_list` to your model's attributes (which it sounds like you do not want to do), or combine the output of `toJSON` with `extra_list` and pass that to your template.

Edit: As noted in the comments, you can use `_.extend` to "merge" extra_list with your model's attributes:

```
  render: function () {
    this.extra_list = _.shuffle(this.extra_list); 

    var data = _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), this.extra_list);

    this.$el.html(this.template(data));
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: OK, what's the best way to combine them? Do I simply write this.template(jQuery.extend(this.model.toJSON(), this.extra_list)?

Comment: @user1813867: I'd `_.extend(this.model.toJSON(), this.extra_list)`, the default `toJSON` returns a copy of the model's `attributes` so you don't have to worry about `_.extend` overwriting anything private. You could use `$.extend` instead of `_.extend` if you wanted.